# Data inserting in descending order - Can't figure out why

Tags: php, mysql

I've form elements named in ascending order such as

```
<input type="text" name="v1[abc]" />
<input type="text" name="v2[abc]" />
<input type="text" name="v3[abc]" />
<input type="text" name="v4[abc]" />
```

I'm processing these values using

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

   $v = $_POST['v'.$i];

   insert('tablename', $v);
}
```

Below is the insert function being used

```
function insert($tableName, $array) {

    array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $array );

    $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$tableName." ( ". implode( ',', array_keys( $array) ) .") VALUES( '". implode( "','", $array ) . "')");

    if(! $qry) {
      die(mysql_error());
    }

}
```

If I enter 1 inside the first textbox, 2 inside the second textbox and so on, after insertion this is what I get in my table

```
----
abc |
----
4   |
3   |
2   |
1   |
----
```

This is quite baffling and I'm not able to find out why this is happening. This is important to me because I want the values to be inserted in the same order that they were entered.

It's kind of hard to explain the reason behind the `enter in the same order` requirement but are there any possible reasons as to why the data is being entered in the descending order?

Comment: MySQL tables don't have an order; if you want resultsets to be in some particular order, you must specify an `ORDER BY` clause to your `SELECT` statements.

Comment: I'd do some print_r of the `$array` in different places of the code to check if it's being reversed in any function. Also checking mysql log to check the real query order of the `INSERT` could give you some hints.

Comment: @eggyal I realize that and using `ORDER BY` will solve my problem, but is there a particular reason for the reverse order inside the table?

Comment: @Naryl I already tried that and the arrays were printed out in order, that is v1 array first, then v2 array etc.

Comment: I suspect they are being entered in the right order, just not displaying as such, hence your confusion

Comment: add a timestamp column with default current_timestamp you'll see the order they were inserted then.

Comment: @Dale That's worth a shot. I'll certainly try that out

Comment: then just check your mysql log, if the `INSERT` there are in the correct order, they are ok in the table. adding a `auto_increment` field to the table should make them return in order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that tables have order is wrong. You get the order you want when you retrieve data by using the `ORDER BY` SQL clause. Otherwise, tables are unsorted.

**Update:** Yep, in the end, databases are nothing but files. But the exact algorithm that MySQL follows to write on disk sectors can only be guessed by looking at the C source code, although I can figure out what the general guideline is: put stuff where you think it'll be faster to do. When you do a `SELECT` without `ORDER BY` you tend to obtain the same apparent order but it's only because it wouldn't make sense for MySQL to waste resources trying to sort or randomize the rows for no good reason. A simple `OPTIMIZE TABLE` can alter this row order.

Comment: I realize that tables don't have order, but is there a reason as to why the data in my particular case is being entered in the reverse order?

Comment: By looking at the table in phpmyadmin

Comment: Then why is that only this table is giving me trouble. I have around 20+ tables in which I use the same process and in those tables the data is in order?

Comment: Does this particular table (the one giving you grief) have an auto increment primary index?

Comment: I'm sorry you don't believe me but table data in relational databases is unsorted by default. If you rely on the apparent default order for anything your code will break sooner or later.

Comment: @Dale Nope. It does have a foreign key though, but it's not the `abc` column

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You got me wrong there buddy. I do believe you. What is troubling me is the behavior of this particular table.

Answer (score 1):

It could be (related to) the way the table was created, you can alter the order by running an sql statement similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ORDER BY `id_column`
```

Which should then set the default to ascending on that column.

Another method would be to add and `ORDER BY` to your select statements:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `id_column` ASC
```

Comment: *ORDER BY enables you to create the new table with the rows in a specific order. Note that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes.* [Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: +1 for the `Order By` suggestion. I can't believe I missed out something so basic. But I'm gonna accept Alvaro's answer as it does shed light on my plight.

Comment: Yes and the point he makes about ORDER BY is something I wasn't aware of myself :)